# Friendly URLs for localhost ASP.NET websites

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, localhost, friendly-url

I Use Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET 4.0 and IIS7.
When I open my site, the URL looks like this

```
http://localhost:6549/Website/help/tab/contact-us
```

I want a friendly URL:

```
http://mysite/help/tab/contact-us
```

or anything that will help me to get rid of the Port `6549` from URL

```
http://localhost/Website/help/tab/contact-us
```

I use ASP.NET Development Server which is what Visual Studio use when you run a localhost website

---

Wait !! Please make distinction between "Properties window" and "Property pages" of the project. I always tried your advices, but using "Property pages", and there is no such property like **Use dynamic ports** on that page. This property can be found only in the "Properties window"

Comment: Have you tried adding a new host header by modifying the website bindings in IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's the ASP.NET development server:

To get rid of the port number you need to do this
- go to properties of the project
- click the web tab 
- check the specific port and assign 80 
There is also a virtual path setting here which you could set to /

Comment: I found the Virtual Path in the Properties Window but there is not "web tab" in the Property Pages of my web application. There are only these tabs: References, Build, Accessibility, MSBuild Options, Silverlight Applications

Comment: I found the "web tab". It is called the Developer Web Server and can be found in the Properties Window

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I was thinking you can use your host file to redirect the user, but I checked and you can't redirect to a port.

If you have IIS7 on the machine, just make the location of your web development folder into a virtual directory on IIS.

Then you can access it by http://localhost/website/

Comment: How did you set up the virtual directory in IIS?  Did you mark it as an application?

Comment: i just discovered I don't have IIS7 installed, only the ASP.NET Development Server was there, which is installed at the same time with VS 2010. I found this http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/ and I'll come back after installing IIS7 on localhost

Comment: @David. Yes, set up the website folder as an application.

Answer (score 1):

Is your solution configured to use IIS and not the ASP.NET Development Server?  There is also a property on the web application where you can specify the port (or allow for a random port to be chosen) - port 80 is the appropriate port - this requires administrator access to the process that is launching the web site.

Comment: by default, ASP.NET Development Server it's used